# I'm attempting to calculate and plot the histogram of the temperatures (Tmax and Tmin) and reporting mode, median, and extrema of the distributions

Tags: python, matplotlib

Currently my issue is only in running the calculation for the Tmax (temperature maximum).  When I run the code I get:

```
    meanTmax = Tmax.mean(Tmax)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'mean'
```

The code is also supposed to calculate and plot the histogram for the 10 year time period indicated in the code below from a data file 'DallasTX.txt'.
This is my current code (with what I thought relevant to the problem):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
import datetime

def ReadData(fname, filterYear):    
    '''    
Read the temperature variation data and append four lists containing the maximum
temperatures as floats, the minimum temperatures as floats, the average
temperatures as floats, and the dates as string YYYYMMDD format.
    '''
    fileObj = open(fname,'r') # associate the fileObj variable with filename
    lineList = fileObj.readlines() # read all lines in file and returns them into a list
    fileObj.close
    Tmin = [] # initialize Temp list - Tmin
    Tmax = [] # initialize Temp list - Tmax
    Tave = [] # initialize Temp list - Tave
    dates = [] # initialize date list
    nHeaderLines = 2 # number of lines to skip
    for line in range(nHeaderLines, len(lineList)): # loop over lines in the list   
        itemList = lineList[line].split() # split current line
        TMIN = float(itemList[12])
        TMAX = float(itemList[11])
        TAVE = float(itemList[10])
        dateList = int(itemList[9])        
        #Convert from file the date string to date time object
        formatedDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(dateList),"%Y%m%d").date()
        #Check the year condition and only select only that data for plotting
        if formatedDate.year in filterYear:        
            Tmin.append(TMIN)
            Tmax.append(TMAX)
            Tave.append(TAVE)
            dates.append(formatedDate)
    return Tmin,Tmax,Tave,dates
##################################################################

def main():
    fname = 'DallasTX.txt' # initialize filename
    print('Reading file: ',fname)    
    #Remember range is exclusive for the upper limit, So range(2010,2021,1) returns 2010 until 2020
    filterYear = range(2010,2019,1)
    #Call the ReadData() function which returns a list of min, max, Avg, Temp, date, year, month, day values
    Tmin, Tmax, Tave, dates = ReadData(fname, filterYear) 
    dates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(str(d),"%Y-%m-%d").date() for d in dates]  

################################################################
# stats calculations
#    MinTmax = Tmax.min()
#    MaxTmax = Tmax.max()
    meanTmax = Tmax.mean(Tmax)
    medianTmax = np.median(Tmax)
    histTmax, binEdges = np.histogram(Tmax)      
    imode = np.argmax(histTmax)
    modeTmax = 0.5*(binEdges[imode] + binEdges[imode+1])
    
    histtuples = plt.hist(Tmax)
    plt.plot(medianTmax,0,'rx',markersize=12,label='median:{}'.format(medianTmax))
    plt.plot(meanTmax,0,'ro',markersize=12,label='mean:{}'.format(meanTmax))
    plt.plot(modeTmax,histTmax[imode],'r+',markersize=12,label='mode:{}'.format(modeTmax))
    plt.legend()
main()
```

This is a small sample of what the data file being read looks like if it helps to understand part of my code and what is being read:

```
STATION           STATION_NAME                                       ELEVATION  LATITUDE   LONGITUDE  DATE     TAVG     TMAX     TMIN     
----------------- -------------------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------- -------- -------- -------- 
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20100101 -9999    51       27       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20100102 -9999    53       30       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20100103 -9999    46       32       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20100104 -9999    37       27       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20100105 -9999    41       23       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20100106 -9999    49       31       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20100107 -9999    46       23       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20100108 -9999    30       17       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20100109 -9999    38       14       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20100110 -9999    44       18       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20100111 -9999    56       27       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20100112 -9999    58       28       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20100113 -9999    62       37       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20100114 -9999    55       50       
GHCND:USW00013960                           DALLAS FAA AIRPORT TX US      134.1    32.8519   -96.8555 20100115 -9999    57       47
```

Comment: `Tmax` is a list, and "'list' objects have no attribute 'mean'". You probably meant to convert `Tmin`, `Tmax` and friends to NumPy arrays

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just meant to type `meanTmax = np.mean(Tmax)`, which should work.

I'd also note that you're living a little dangerously in `ReadData` by assuming that the STATION_NAME is exactly 5 words. Better to use the fixed layout and skip past all the fields you don't want (102 characters), so with a few style adjustments that becomes:

```py
    for oneline in lineList[nHeaderLines:]: # loop over non-header lines in the list   
        fields = oneline[102:].split()      # split DATE/TAVG/TMAX/TMIN from current line
        #Convert the date field to date time object
        formatedDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(fields[0],"%Y%m%d").date()
        #Check the year condition and only select only that data for plotting
        if formatedDate.year in filterYear:
            dates.append(formatedDate)
            TAVE, TMAX, TMIN = map(float,fields[1:4])
            Tmin.append(TMIN)
            Tmax.append(TMAX)
            Tave.append(TAVE)
```